# How to select an element from a class attribute inside of another class attribute using Criteria Builder Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have this class:

**Dependencia.java**

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_DEPENDENTE")
private Dependente dependente;
```

Inside of **Dependente.java**

```
@OneToOne(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinColumn(name = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA", referencedColumnName = "ID_PESSOA_FISICA")
private PessoaFisica pessoaFisica;
```

and inside of **PessoaFisica.java**

```
@Column(name = "NM_PESSOA_FISICA", nullable = false, length = 50)
@NotBlank(message = "{MSG-24}")
String nome;
```

What I want is selecting **nome** using CriteriaBuilder, something like:

```
query.multiselect(dependencia.join("dependente").join("pessoaFisica").get("nome"));
```

I tried using this, but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Well,

```
query.multiselect(dependencia.join("dependente", JoinType.LEFT).join("pessoaFisica", JoinType.LEFT).get("nome"))
```

Now, it worked. Mods feel free to close my question. Thanks!